# How to fix forbidden URL redirect in Liferay 7.4.2?

Tags: apache, liferay, tomcat9, liferay-7

I'm having a redirect issue with the platform Liferay 7.4.2 CE version. I deployed the portal using a Tomcat 9 server, and it is running behind an Apache SSL reverse proxy in a Debian OS.

Most of the functionalities work normally, but it is not possible to create/edit workflows because the component is not showing in the interface:

[image]

The only error in the logs is:

```
2021-11-08 12:22:11.043 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-9][PortalImpl:1042] Redirect URL https://host/group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=com_liferay_portal_workflow_web_portlet_ControlPanelWorkflowPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&_com_liferay_portal_workflow_web_portlet_ControlPanelWorkflowPortlet_mvcPath=%2Fview.jsp is not allowed
```

I've been reading some discussion threads and I saw that in previous versions this issue was remediated by setting the properties redirect.url.security.mode and redirect.url.domains.allowed properties, but I found that such properties are deprecated in version 7.4.2.

I tried to set several different properties in the portal-ext.properties file (e.g. `web.server.https.port`, `web.server.host`, `portal.instance.inet.socket.address`) but so far none of this worked out.

Does someone know if there is a way to solve this issue directly in the Apache server? Or if there is a new Liferay property that allows for whitelisting domains/IPs?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824). Voting to close here as it's not a development- but configuration related question (see [help/on-topic]), and it's been answered already in your crosspost

Comment: Hi Olaf, you're right, sorry about the crossposting.

Answer (score 1):

Just to not leave this unanswered: I got the solution by talking on Liferay's Slack channel, the domains/IPs allowed are now set in the Redirect URLs configuration that is accessible through the control panel > instance settings.
The redirection errors disappeared when this configuration was set, but turns out that was not the reason why the workflow editor was not appearing. The actual reason is that the graphic workflow editor is not available for community editions, that is just for the enterprise version.